# How to assert the values in a downloaded file using Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

I am downloading a zip file which has a json zipped. Using cy.readfile, I am able to read the content but I am not sure what commands can be used to assert on the values inside. 
(Please let me know if there is a way to unzip the file before reading)
I need to verify I have 3 objectids present in the json and also some values of the elements.
I tried the below approach, but it did not work.

```js
cy.readFile(`/Users/${username}/Downloads/${fileName}.zip`) 
  .should('contain','objectid').and('have.length',3);
```

The above command did not work for me :(

Could someone help me with some examples? I am new to cypress and coding,therefore struggling a little.
[image: Attaching an image of how cy.readfile of the zip file looks like. As highlighted in the image, I need to assert on having 2 objectid's present in the file and some other values as well.]

Comment: The file is downloaded to downloads folder and not to fixture.

Comment: I checked many posts, and nowhere is it mentioned how to change the file downloads location. I just updated the post with an image of how the cy.readfile looks like. I actually need some inisght on how to assert on the values inside the json. normal assertion commands are not exactly working in this case

Comment: cy.fixture() doesn't seem to work..
Error: A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:tests\e2e\fixtures\Task1.exportZip.zip
I think unzipping is not much of a problem, but I need help with some examples for assertion. This is a very basic question but some examples would be helpful. If you could look at the image in the post and give me an example to assert that the file has 2 objectid's.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the download folder in every test case!!

Look into your index.js in -> cypress -> plugins -> index.js and write this :

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
 on('before:browser:launch', (browser, options) => {
    const downloadDirectory = 'C:\\downloads\\';    // this is the path you want to download

    options.preferences.default['download'] = { default_directory: downloadDirectory };

    return options;
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
cy.readFile(`/Users/${username}/Downloads/${fileName}.zip`)
 .then((data) => {
      // you can write whatever assertions you want on data 
      debugger;
      console.log(data);
      expect(data).to....
  })
```

You can put debugger as above and logs to check what data contains and then assert

Use this link to know about available assertions https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions

Comment: (Please let me know if there is a way to unzip the file before reading) I added this in bracket because it is not a blocker for me.cy.readfile is able to read a zip file without unzipping.
 https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions this link is really useful but since I am new to cypress, if someone could give me some basic examples based on the attached image it would be really helpful.

Comment: It is unlikely you can test against the raw contents of a zip file. You should first unpack it to obtain the JSON content first.

Comment: @Ackroydd Do you know how to unpack it in cypress?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the approach I am following.It is quite lengthy, but still posting as it might be helpful for someone.Please comment if you have any suggestions for improvements here.
I am using npm-unzipper to unzip the downloaded file.

Step 1: $ npm install unzipper

Step 2:In plugins > index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const osplatform = os.platform();
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const userName = os.userInfo().username;
let downloadPath =`/${userName}/Downloads/`; 
  if (osplatform == 'win32'){
    downloadPath = `/Users/${userName}/Downloads/`;        
  }
on('task', {
        extractzip(zipname) {
            const zipPath = downloadPath + zipname; 
            if (fs.existsSync(zipPath)) {
              const readStream = fs.createReadStream(zipPath);
              readStream.pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: `${downloadPath}`}));
              const jsonname = 'testfile.json'
              const jsonPath = downloadPath + jsonname;
              return jsonPath;
            }
            else{
              console.error('file not downloaded')
              return null; 
            }
        }
  })
```

Step 3:support > commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('comparefiles', { prevSubject: false }, (subject, options = {}) => {
    cy.task('extractzip', 'exportfile.zip').then((jsonPath) => {
        cy.fixture('export.json').then((comparefile) => {
            cy.readFile(jsonPath).then((exportedfile) => {
                var exported_objectinfo = exportedfile.objectInfo;
                var compare_objectinfo = comparefile.objectInfo;
                var exported_metaInfo = exportedfile.metaInfo;
                var compare_metaInfo = comparefile.metaInfo;
                expect(exported_objectinfo).to.contain.something.like(compare_objectinfo)
                expect(exported_metaInfo).to.have.deep.members(compare_metaInfo)
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Step 4: specs > exportandcompare.js

```
cy.get('[data-ci-button="Export"]').click();
cy.comparefiles();
```